# Convert Query Cursor Data to URL's and Run it in AsyncTask

Tags: android, url, android-asynctask

Hi I am using a function that looks like this. It converts a string to URL's

```
protected URL stringToURL(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        return url;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and sample use of that is this.

```
final URL url1  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image1.jpg");
```

and if i want to use more i will just use it like this.

```
final URL url1  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image1.jpg");
final URL url2  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image2.jpg");
final URL url3  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image3.jpg");
final URL url4  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image4.jpg");
final URL url5  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image5.jpg");
final URL url6  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image6.jpg");
final URL url7  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image7.jpg");
final URL url8  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image8.jpg");
final URL url9  = stringToURL("www.link_to_my_page/sample_image9.jpg");
```

and then i have an `AsyncTask` that will process all of that and here it is

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, ArrayList<image_class>> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected ArrayList<image_class> doInBackground(URL... urls) {

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onCancelled() {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<image_class> result) {

    }
}
```

and if i want to run my `AsyncTask` i will call it like this

```
mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(url1);
```

or for multiple

```
mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6,url7,url8,url9);
```

and now here is my concern. all my links where inside my `SQLite` Database and what I did so far is create a `Cursor` Loop them while using `stringToURL` inside an array then call it like this `mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(Array_of_Urls.ToString());` but no luck and it gave an errors.

My question is how can call that task using my urls in database?

Here is my current code

on Create Method

```
load_sync = findViewById(R.id.load_sync);
mProgressAnimation = new ProgressBarAnimation(load_sync, 100);

startMyAsyncTaskWithURList();
```

and here is the whole code

```
private ArrayList<URL> getMyURLFromDB() {
    ArrayList<URL> listURL = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = Sync.get_image(current_email);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String folder = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("folder"));
        String urlString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("myimage"));
        String gen_link = "Custom URL" + folder + "/" + urlString;
        Log.e("Link ", "" + gen_link);
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(gen_link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listURL.add(url);
    }
    return listURL;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<image_class>> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    ArrayList<URL> listURL = null;
    public DownloadTask(ArrayList<URL> urls){
        this.listURL = urls;
    }

    protected ArrayList<image_class> doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count = listURL.size();
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        ArrayList<image_class> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            URL currentURL = listURL.get(i);
            String fileName = currentURL.toString().substring(currentURL.toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) currentURL.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
                bitmaps.add(new image_class(bmp,fileName));

                publishProgress((int) (((i + 1) / (float) count) * 100));
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return bitmaps;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mProgressAnimation.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<image_class> result) {
        Iterator itr = result.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            image_class st = (image_class) itr.next();
            Bitmap bitmap = st.image;
            saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, st.filename);
        }
    }
}

protected Uri saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
    File file = sdCardDirectory;
    file = new File(file, filename);

    try {
        OutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return savedImageURI;
}
```

the image doesnt download or the AsyncTask is not working

Comment: `ArrayList<URL> listURL = new ArrayList<>();`  pass your `ArrayList` to your `AsyncTask` :: `private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<URL>, Integer, ArrayList<image_class>> {`  ::: But do you really think you need the method `stringToURL()`??

Comment: u mean i will create an `ArrayList<URL> listURL = new ArrayList<>()` then insert the links from `Cursor`?

Comment: if i will pass it inside `ArrayList` maybe I wont need `stringToURL` and also can u provide me some sample?

Comment: @Barns done creating arraylist how can I pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a basic outline:

```
private ArrayList<> getMyURLFromDB(){
    ArrayList<> listURL = new ArrayList<>();

    // You will need to fill in some blanks here...
    //... This is just a basic outline!
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbModel.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db....
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String urlString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MY_URL_STRING));
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        listURL.add(url);
    }
    return listURL;
}
```

Get the List from the database and pass the `ArrayList` as a parameter of the `AsyncTask`:

```
private void startMyAsyncTaskWithURList(){
    ArrayList<URL> listURL = getMyURLFromDB();
    // Just pass the ArrayList as a parameter
    new DownloadTask(listURL).execute();
}
```

You need to add a constructor of the `AsyncTask` that will accept the `ArrayList`as a parameter:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<image_class>> {

    ArrayList<URL> listURL = null;
    public DownloadTask(ArrayList<URL> urls){
        this.listURL = urls;    
    }

    protected ArrayList<image_class> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Now you have access to the list
        if(listURL != null){
        }

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<image_class> result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: i will try this definitely Thnx sir :)

Comment: The code for `getMyURLFromDB()` is basically just a stub--you need to adapt it to your code.  The important thing is you use `while(cursor.moveToNext()){` to fill the `ArrayList` with the data from your database. You might be getting an error because a string value might not generate a valid `URL`. But without any further information I can't help you with the error.

Comment: for me this is one of the best pattern i can follow. tysm and i will accept. I will update you later on. this is too much

Comment: Just send me a comment if you have any questions, no worries! Be sure to specify the type of error if you get an error.

Comment: noted on this. I have an issue now i will post the whole code

Comment: currently fixing but still no luck

Comment: @myownemail :: It is best if you try to download a single URL image then display that image in an `ImageView` just to test if the files are being downloaded properly. Instead of HttpURLConnection you can also use this to download the file: `InputStream is = currentURL.openStream();  Bitmap bmp = BitmaoFactory.decodeStream(is);`

Comment: @myownemail :: I know it is more work but you should take the code you are using now and post a new question describing the issue you are now having since the initial issue has been fixed. One big advantage to this would be that you will have more SO users looking at the new question and particularly so now since the title does not indicate the issue you are having now.